# WebApp in .Net C# 4.5.1 is not working for TLS 1.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, tls1.2, boomi

WebApplication written in Asp.Net C# 4.5.1 is working fine for TLS1.0 and TLS 1.1. But since 1.0 and 1.1 have been disabled and TLS 1.2 is enabled the app have an issue when making calls to the Exum Service
"https://connect.boomi.com/ws/rest/exum".
The error details is as:
Error details:System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm  .

I tried by adding the code in global.asax
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; but no luck.

Can anyone advise on this case please.

Comment: The other solution you can try is by adding registry keys to enable TLS1.2. If not, check with your API service, if they have some settings/configuration or any certificate.

Comment: I enabled the TLS 1.2 in registry key through regedit and rebooted the server as well but doesn't work. checked with API provider as well and they confirmed API is fine for TLS 1.2. Now the rest is certificate. Could you please explain a bit more in certificate ..Thanks